# Lucene Query not working

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Apache Lucene 5.0.0 and ran into problems using QueryParser. I tried to create a Query but I get a ParseException.

The following is my code:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;

public class QueryTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("field", new StandardAnalyzer());
        try {
            parser.Query("query");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exception that I'm getting:

```
org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 0.
Was expecting one of:
    <NOT> ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    <BAREOPER> ...
    "(" ...
    "*" ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <TERM> ...
    <PREFIXTERM> ...
    <WILDTERM> ...
    <REGEXPTERM> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    <NUMBER> ...
    <TERM> ...
    "*" ...

    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.generateParseException(QueryParser.java:698)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.jj_consume_token(QueryParser.java:580)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:265)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:171)
    at QueryTest.main(QueryTest.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

If it helps, I have included the following jar files:

- lucene-analyzers-common-5.0.0.jar
- lucene-core-5.0.0.jar
- lucene-queries-5.0.0.jar
- lucene-queryparser-5.0.0.jar
- lucene-sandbox-5.0.0.jar

I have no idea why this exception is thrown and how to solve it. The examples online are similar but seems to be working fine for them.

Thank You.

Comment: how your query looks like?

Comment: It is literally the one shown in the code above. It's the single word, "query".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just using the wrong method, what you are trying to do is:

```
    QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("field", new StandardAnalyzer());
    try {
        Query query = parser.parse("query"); // changed this line
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation:

The syntax for query strings is as follows:
 A Query is a series of clauses.
 A clause may be prefixed by:

- a plus (`+`) or a minus (`-`) sign, indicating
   that the clause is required or prohibited respectively; or

  a term followed by a colon, indicating the field to be searched.
   This enables one to construct queries which search multiple fields.

A clause may be either:

- a term, indicating all the documents that contain this term; or

  a nested query, enclosed in parentheses.  Note that this may be used
   with a `+`/`-` prefix to require any of a set of
   terms.

Thus, in BNF, the query grammar is:

```
   Query  ::= ( Clause )*
   Clause ::= ["+", "-"] [<TERM> ":"] ( <TERM> | "(" Query ")" )
```

For more information take a look here - http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParser.html

To solve your problem in particular it may be worth to parse "field:Query" string as a query